# How can i access multiple object in a nested array and push them all at the same time using Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentperson: -1,
    people: [{
      nome: "Francesco Rossio",
      immagine: "img/profile1.jpg",
      oraUltimoMessaggio: "13:32",
      messaggiNonLetti: "2",
      visibile: true,
      messaggi: [{
        date: '10/01/2020 15:30:55',
        text: 'Hei tu, sei molto carino, sai?',
        status: 'sent'
      }, {
        date: '10/01/2020 15:50:00',
        text: 'Sai che mi piacciono le ciabatte?',
        status: 'sent'
      }, {
        date: '10/01/2020 16:15:22',
        text: 'Ora sai tutto di me.',
        status: 'received'
      }],
    },
```

this is my array and my object, I want all of the "text" object to be cycled once with a `v-for`. Is it possible?
I've been trying for hours whatever I do I can't get at the end of it.

Comment: Hint: you need two for loop

Answer (score 2):

The arrays should be rendered with the [`v-for` directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#mapping-an-array-to-elements-with-v-for), nesting the `v-for` for the nested array:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="person in people" :key="person.nome">
    <span>{{ person.nome }}</span>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="msg in person.messaggi" :key="msg.date">{{ msg.text }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-render-nested-arrays?file=src/App.vue)